# java error actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, exception

This is the error I am getting...

```
TestingCode_ExtraAssignment2_through_6.java:707: error: constructor CarException in class CarException cannot be applied to given types;
       if ( resultsOfTest==false ) throw new CarException(s);
                                         ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Here is the method that is throwing the exception:

```
public void setYear(int y) throws CarException
{
    if (y >= 1970 && y <=2011)
        year = y;
    else 
        throw new CarException("Error");
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
public class CarException extends Exception{

    public CarException(String m)
    {
        String message = m;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `CarException` on your classpath that takes no args. Try cleaning & rebuilding

Comment: Where are these variables in your compilation error coming from?

Comment: Clean and rebuild it!